# the better the results

Tags: phrase-choice, minor-sentences

Which of the following phrases is correct? Could you explain why?

> *The more often you do this, **the better the results***.

> *The more often you do this, **the better the results are***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're both fine in my opinion - you can think of *the better the results are* as the more general form:

- *The more often you do this, the better the results **are***
- *The more often you do this, the better the results **will be***
- *The more often you did this, the better the results **were***

The verb is especially important when you need to be specific about tense, but it's common to omit it - but it's still implied, the sentence doesn't make grammatical sense without a verb. Try it with a less familiar phrasing:

- *The later it gets, the more the rain*

You want it to say *the more the rain **falls***, or *the more **it rains***, right? But when it's the *copula* (the *be* verb used as *thing **is** something*) it's often dropped, because people understand it's implied.

Answer (score 0):

IMO the second example is a bit strange, because of the "are" at the end, I think the first sentence:

> The more often you do this, the better the results.

Is more grammatical than the second.